# Extracting text from pdf using Python and Pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, text, pypdf

I want to extract text from pdf file using Python and PYPDF package.
This is my [pdf](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AsKGn_8dPumMaxMdoZ-xaMcrwDg) fie and this is my code:

```
import PyPDF2
opened_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('test.pdf', 'rb')

p=opened_pdf.getPage(0)

p_text= p.extractText()
# extract data line by line
P_lines=p_text.splitlines()
print P_lines
```

My problem is P_lines cannot extract data line by line and results in one giant string. I want to extract text line by line to analyze it. Any suggestion on how to improve it?
Thanks!
This is the string that code returns:

> [u'Ingredient information for chemicals subject to 29 CFR 1910.1200(i)
>   and Appendix D are obtained from suppliers Material Safety Data Sheets
>   (MSDS)** Information is based on the maximum potential for
>   concentration and thus the total may be over 100%* Total Water Volume
>   sources may include fresh water, produced water, and/or recycled
>   water0.01271%72.00%7732-18-5Water0.00071%4.00%1310-73-2Sodium
>   Hydroxide0.00424%24.00%533-74-4DazomatBiocidePumpcoPlexcide
>   24L0.00828%75.00%Organic phosphonic acid
>   salts0.00276%25.00%67-56-1Methyl AlcoholScale InhibitorPumpcoPlexaid
>   6730.00807%30.00%7732-18-5Water0.00188%7.00%Polyethoxylated alcohol surfactants0.00753%28.00%9003-06-9Ammonium
>   Salts0.00941%35.00%64742-47-8Petroleum DistillateFriction
>   ReducerPumpcoPlexslick
>   9210.05029%60.00%7732-18-5Water0.03353%40.00%7647-01-0Hydrogen ChlorideHydrochloric AcidPumpcoHCL9.84261%100.00%14808-60-7Crystaline
>   SilicaProppantPumpcoSand90.01799%100.00%7732-18-5WaterCommentsMaximumIngredientConcentrationin HF Fluid(% by mass)**MaximumIngredientConcentrationin Additive(% by
>   mass)**Chemical AbstractService Number(CAS
>   #)IngredientsPurposeSupplierTrade NameHydraulic Fracturing Fluid Composition:2,608,032Total Water Volume (gal)*:7,595True Vertical
>   Depth (TVD):GasProduction Type:NAD27Long/Lat
>   Projection:32.558525Latitude:-97.215242Longitude:Ole Gieser Unit D
>   6HWell Name and Number:XTO EnergyOperator Name:42-439-35084API
>   Number:TarrantCounty:TexasState:12/10/2010Fracture DateHydraulic
>   Fracturing Fluid Product Component Information Disclosure']

Screenshot of the file:
[image]

Comment: can we see an example of the string returned

Comment: this is what it returns: [u'Ingredient information for chemicals subject to 29 CFR 1910.1200(i) and Appendix D are obtained from suppliers Material Safety Data Sheets (MSDS)** Information is based on the maximum potential for concentration and thus the total may be over 100%* Total Water Volume sources may include fresh water, produced water, and/or recycled water0.01271%72.00%7732-18-5Water0.00071%4.00%1310-73-2Sodium Hydroxide0.00424%24.00%533-74-4DazomatBiocidePumpcoPlexcide 24L0.00828%....

Comment: add that string to the question its not very clear in the comment, also can you indicate where in the string you would expect the newline to occur

Comment: just added to question

Comment: Does the PDF have `\n` newlines?

Comment: no it doesn't! I think since this pdf is generated from Excel, PYPDF2 has issues reading it and extracting text line by line

Comment: Then that's the problem. `string.splitlines()` splits a string when it finds a newline.

Comment: ok so what do you suggest to use instead of splitlines()? thanks

Comment: Can you paste the original PDF? Or at least the first page?

Comment: a screenshot of the pdf would do.

Comment: I added screenshot of pdf file. Also pdf file is attached to SKYDRIVE

Comment: @Amir see my answer, since it has been two years, wondering if this solution works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
print(convert_pdf_to_txt('test.pdf').strip().split('\n\n'))
```

Output

> Hydraulic Fracturing Fluid Product Component Information Disclosure
>
> Fracture Date State: County: API Number: Operator Name: Well Name and
>   Number: Longitude: Latitude: Long/Lat Projection: Production Type:
>   True Vertical Depth (TVD): Total Water Volume (gal)*:
>
> 12/10/2010 Texas Tarrant 42-439-35084 XTO Energy Ole Gieser Unit D 6H
>   -97.215242
>   32.558525 NAD27 Gas 7,595 2,608,032
>
> Hydraulic Fracturing Fluid Composition:
>
> Trade Name
>
> Supplier
>
> Purpose
>
> Ingredients
>
> Chemical Abstract Service Number
>
> (CAS #)
>
> Maximum Ingredient
>
> Concentration
>
> in Additive ( by mass)**
>
> Comments
>
> Maximum Ingredient
>
> Concentration
>
> in HF Fluid ( by mass)**
>
> Water Sand HCL
>
> Pumpco Pumpco
>
> Proppant Hydrochloric Acid
>
> Plexslick 921
>
> Pumpco
>
> Friction Reducer
>
> Plexaid 673
>
> Pumpco
>
> Scale Inhibitor
>
> Plexcide 24L
>
> Pumpco
>
> Biocide
>
> Crystaline Silica
>
> Hydrogen Chloride Water
>
> Petroleum Distillate Ammonium Salts Polyethoxylated alcohol
>   surfactants Water
>
> Methyl Alcohol Organic phosphonic acid salts
>
> Dazomat Sodium Hydroxide Water
>
> 7732-18-5 14808-60-7
>
> 7647-01-0 7732-18-5
>
> 64742-47-8 9003-06-9
>
> 7732-18-5
>
> 67-56-1
>
> 533-74-4 1310-73-2 7732-18-5
>
> 100.00
>   100.00
>
> 90.01799
>   9.84261
>
> 40.00
>   60.00
>
> 35.00
>   28.00
>   7.00
>   30.00
>
> 25.00
>   75.00
>
> 24.00
>   4.00
>   72.00
>
> 0.03353
>   0.05029
>
> 0.00941
>   0.00753
>   0.00188
>   0.00807
>
> 0.00276
>   0.00828
>
> 0.00424
>   0.00071
>   0.01271
>
> - Total Water Volume sources may include fresh water, produced water, and/or recycled water
>     ** Information is based on the maximum potential for concentration and thus the total may be over 100
>
> Ingredient information for chemicals subject to 29 CFR 1910.1200(i)
>   and Appendix D are obtained from suppliers Material Safety Data Sheets
>   (MSDS)

Comment: I get following code when I run your code: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: what is your Python version? I am using 2.7.

Comment: Python 2.7.12  Windows 10

Comment: no I didn't manage to do it unfortunately I get the same error listed above. However, even if I code works, it is not going to be useful because it is not parsing line by line. thanks for your effort

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

The character \xe9 is é

Comment: for python 3 and above one have to use `io` instead of `cStringIO`

Comment: @Amir  splited to lines

Answer (score 3):

`textract` works fine in python3, using the `tesseract` method. Example code:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("pdfs/testpdf1.pdf", method='tesseract')
print(text)
with open('textract-results.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(str(text))
```

https://pypi.org/project/textract/

Comment: I think textract is not the right answer here. It's more like an enterprise solution. You can't access it without a credit card. Generally, people here are looking for open source solutions or some coding based solution whereas this is more like a blackbox solution which is also paid. So I think it would have been better if there were a disclaimer before the solution, something like "this might not be the right solution for everyone as it's more like an enterprise solution provided by aws". This answer wasted my time instead of saving it. So downvoted.

Comment: @penduDev please see my update to my answer. At the time of my answer Amazon did not have a thing called Textract which is unfortunately the same name as an open source library in pypi. Please download and use this one: https://pypi.org/project/textract/ as it really does work that easy out of the box. And please remove the downvote, since your assumption about AWS / enterprise solution was wrong. I very much seek and use open source solutions and share them here and everywhere I can.

Comment: oh.. i misunderstood! thanks for clarification @jamescampbell  ..My problem was solved another way, but hope someone else find this helpful. Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the PDF you are importing actually has newlines in it. If it doesn't, then there is nowhere for `p_text.splitlines()` to split the string! If there is a specific character, you can use `p_text.split("the linebreak character")`.

EDIT: Based on your PDF, I'm not sure there is a way to split this by line since it seems to be statically formatted rather than linearly. (text is placed by position in the PDF, not line-by-line).

Comment: Yes splitlines() doesn't work. Is there any other pdf extraction package than can accomplish this?

Comment: @Amir see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I came up with that was completely based on the @SmartManoj answer but has been updated to be cleaner (in my opinion) by using `with` statements, eliminating unnecessary variable (i.e., ones that the keyword argument self explains) as well as yielding the page's text.

```
from typing import Generator  
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def pages_as_txt(path) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    with StringIO() as retstr, TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams()) as device:
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

        with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, check_extractable=False):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
                yield retstr.getvalue()
                retstr.truncate(0)
                retstr.seek(0)
```